# Toolbar and Sidebar not showing, handles still visible

Tags: interface, edit-mode

When i loaded up my project today my toolbar and sidebar wouldn't show, despite them being enabled in the view menu. (i.e pressing N & T does not work) If i open a new project they show up. The handles to drag and move the bars are visible, but not the bars themselves. NOTE: I am not looking for the outliner or properties panel. Only the toolbar and sidebar.

I have tried [this thread](https://old.reddit.com/r/blenderhelp/comments/cma2dw/this_is_really_dumb_but_my_ui_all_disappeared_and/ew158m1/) as well as [this one](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/93326/my-right-toolbar-is-gone) but to no avail.
[image: image of the problem]

Comment: Did you try pressing T and N ? What version of Blender are you using ?